# React Native read yaml file

Tags: javascript, react-native, yaml

I'd like to read and parse a static yaml resource file (let's starts from there) within my React Native source code, I tried `require('path/to/file.yaml')` to no avail.

I also tried with npm's libraries such as `read-yaml` or `yaml-loader` all of which cannot get the yaml content properly.

It is a breeze with json file, I can just `require('path/to/file.json') and immediately get everything in nice object format.

Is there a way to read yaml in react native? It is just another text file right with a different format right, so I don't think it will be that hard to read and parse the yaml file., but I am new to JavaScript and React-Native here coming from C/C++ background

Answer (score 0):

Since there appears to be no built-in support for yaml, I believe you would need to use something like [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs), or in [Expo FileSystem.readAsStringAsync](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemreadasstringasyncfileuri-options) (treating the file as an asset). You should then be able to use a library such as [yaml-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml-js) to parse the string as read.

Comment: The thing is it is in local package but if I `require(path/to/it)` or `include(path/to/it)` I'd never have the full content (not even string, it is just some weird number) whereas if I `require(path/to/json') I will have full content of the json...

Comment: As stated in answer, bundler does not have built-in support for that type so `require` and `include` are only going to give you a reference. When you require a JSON, what you get is not a string but evaluated JSON in a JavaScript object. What happens if you have malformed JSON? Error. For this to work with YAML, it would have to be a supported type, which it is not. Check the links I included—neither of which  `require` or `include` the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use require directly to load yaml.
If you're using Expo:

1. use a hook:

```
const [assets, assetsLoadError] = useAssets([
    require(uri)
]);
```

2. load asset (won't work without the hook above):

```
const loadedAsset = await Asset.loadAsync(
    require(uri)
);
```

3. Read the file into a string var:

```
let content;
try {
    content = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(
        loadedAsset.localUri
    );
} catch (e) {
    console.log({ e });
}
```

4. Parse YAML from string, e.g. with YAML npm package:

```
const parsedYAML = YAML.parse(content);
```

Answer (score -1):

First install
`npm install --save babel-plugin-content-transformer`

Then add to your babel config :

```js
plugins: [
        [
            'content-transformer',
            {
                transformers: [
                    {
                        file: /\.ya?ml$/,
                        format: 'yaml',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    ],
```